# My powershell script is not stopping a process that I am opening

Tags: powershell

I am creating a basic powershell script that will open the calculator app, get its process id, and then eventually stop the process itself with confirmation. But when I run the following script on my computer (through Powershell ISE, but it also doesn't seem to work on regular powershell in admin mode), it does not kill the calculator process. I am running Windows 10 Version 21H1.

`Start-Process calc.exe; Get-Process calc; Stop-Process -Name calc -whatif; Stop-Process -Name calc -Confirm -PassThru`

Comment: What happens if you open the run box ([MICROSOFT] + [R] keys) and type `calc` - does it open the calculator? (On my machine this no longer works as the Calculator app is now a store app not an exe on the path you can execute easily which annoys me greatly). Try removing everything after the `-whatif` and possibly add a delay between each command `start-sleep -seconds 5;`. Edit your question with further info/include any output/errors.

Comment: To address your comments

1. Win + R and typing in calc still opens up the default calculator.
2. I put each task on a separate line, and while it still doesn't close the process, it now minimizes it instead, when before it would remained open. I removed the ```what-if``` portion of the script, and the calculator also gets minimized.
3. I tried ```start-sleep``` but powershell says that it is an invalid argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the name **Calculator** instead of **calc** for `Get-Process`. I also had to add a delay between the launching of **calc.exe** and `Stop-Process`. Without the delay, it could not find the process to stop it.

```
Start-Process -FilePath calc.exe
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Get-Process -Name Calculator | Stop-Process
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue, I adapted it minorly to be able to run the ```what-if``` command.